# How can I build two tests which interact with each other in real time, in Sauce + Sausage framework

Tags: saucelabs

Can anyone explain how to generate two simultaneous webdrivers in a Sauce (with Sausage framework) test script?

I need to build a test where two different logged-in users simultaneously visit the same page in my site, to test some real-time stuff in that page. Due to session cookies on my site, I think those two users need to be on separate webdrivers...?

This will form part of a much larger smoke test so writing two tests and simply running them at the same time via ParaTest (for example) isn't going to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Sauce support confirmed that this isn't currently possible.